# Loading of GoogleMap in Compose is really slow

Tags: google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the [Maps Compose Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) to display a map:

```
@Composable
fun Maps(latLng: LatLng, radius: Float) {
    val uiSettings = remember { MapUiSettings(zoomControlsEnabled = false, rotationGesturesEnabled = false) }

    val cameraPosition = CameraPosition(latLng, 15f, 0F, 0F)


    GoogleMap(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), uiSettings = uiSettings, cameraPositionState = CameraPositionState(cameraPosition)) 
}
```

however, the initial loading is very slow:

> Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

So, I was wondering if there is a way to fix this so that the user can interact with the other elements on the screen while the map is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate this-> https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose open-source library through which you will be able to access states like loading, success, failure!

Comment: I think I'm already using this library, but I can't figure out how to monitor these states.

Comment: Could you share an example of what you got working? I'm getting nothing but errors when I try to add that to my Compose ready project. Even their example doesn't work, saying "Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions"